# Non-Parametric Methods Like K-Nearest-Neighbours in High Dimensional Feature Space

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

The main idea of [k-Nearest-Neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) takes into account the $k$ nearest points and decides the classification of the data by majority vote. If so, then it should not have problems in higher dimensional data because methods like [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Locality_sensitive_hashing) can efficiently find nearest neighbours.

In addition, feature selection with Bayesian networks can reduce the dimension of data and make learning easier.

However, this [review paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2038&context=compsci&sei-redir=1&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com.hk%2Fscholar_url%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Frepository.cmu.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%253Farticle%253D2038%2526context%253Dcompsci%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm2_yYj4fmPTEDqBmHIZN-g3FWN7BA%26oi%3Dscholarr%26ei%3DzeB7T6qOIOmwiQeHj8GKCQ%26ved%3D0CBsQgAMoADAA#search=%22http%3A%2F%2Frepository.cmu.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D2038%26context%3Dcompsci%22) by John Lafferty in statistical learning points out that non-parametric learning in high dimensional feature spaces is still a challenge and unsolved.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please give a full reference for the paper; the authors do not seem to appear (prominently) in the it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is known as the [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). Basically, as you increase the number of dimensions, $d$, points in the space generally tend to become far from all other points. This makes partitioning the space (such as is necessary for classification or clustering) very difficult.

You can see this for yourself very easily. I generated $50$ random $d$-dimensional points in the unit hypercube at 20 evenly selected values of $d$ from $1..1000$. For each value of $d$ I computed the distance from the first point to all others and took the average of these distances. Plotting this, we can see that average distance is increasing with dimensionality even though the space in which we are generating the points in each dimension remains the same.

[Average distance vs. dimensionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Czc.jpg)

Comment: Of course. You increase the number of points in a hypersphere of fixed radius exponentially in the dimensionalty, so if you choose 50 points uniformly at random this *has* to happen. Therefore, if your reasoning is correct, partitioning should become easy if I have many samples; is that so?

Comment: I believe you have it reversed. By increasing dimensionality, I REDUCE the number of points within a hypersphere. Partitioning becomes more difficult because the measure of distance essentially loses its meaning (e.g. everything is far away).

Comment: I meant: The total number of points in a hypersphere of radius $k$ in say $\mathbb{N}^n$, i.e. $|\mathbb{N}^n \cap S_n(k)|$ increases with $n$.

Comment: Also note that what people mean when they refer to high-dimensional feature space is that the number of samples, $n$, is much less than the dimensionality of each point, $d$, ($n << d$). So in these problems you assume that you do NOT have 'many samples'.

Comment: I don't see that this holds by definition; it seems to be a convention based on experience, though.

Comment: @Nick In the wikipedia post "curse of dimensionality", it says that methods like Principle Component Analysis works in many cases unless the data have too many irrelevant dimensions. How can you explain the "dimensionality challenge" mentioned in the review paper?

Comment: @Strin, As the review paper by Lafferty states: "Most statistical theory is based on asymptotic approximations that allow the
sample size n to grow large. When the number of variables d in the model is large, this
theory can be misleading...". The challenge he appears to be talking about is building a $theory$ to handle such data. The claim is not that dimensionality reduction methods won't work in certain cases, but that many of the statistical justifications that we take for granted may break down when working on this data.

Comment: @Nick, I've misunderstood the paper. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) you cited states:

> The accuracy of the k-NN algorithm can be severely degraded by the presence of noisy or irrelevant features, or if the feature scales are not consistent with their importance.

The likelihood of this occurring increases in the presence of high dimensional feature spaces.

Comment: But I think with PCA(principle component analysis) or any other methods to reduce dimensionality and remove irrelevant data, k-NN can still work. And what the wikipedia pages mean is the naive k-NN will fail. So this doesn't explain the review paper.

Comment: PCA can certainly work, but not in all situations.